# Migration Process from maven 2 to maven 3 on windows

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

i want to migrate from maven 2 to maven 3 on windows, and i was wondering what are the necessary steps to migrate beside adding an environment variable for the maven 3, are there any changes in pom file ? and is there any other changes or things to put into considerations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find possible issues after upgrading in the [Maven wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html).